# Exibir tabela dinâmica

Tags: javascript, jquery

Estou criando uma tabela dinâmica que a partir dos valores de um objeto, porém na hora de gerar a tabela ela nao esta aparece. Segue o código:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="batata.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="tbldados"></div>
</body>
</html>
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
var dados =[{
    "N1":" CONTROLE DE GESTÃO ORCAMENTARIA CONCESSÕES - INDICADORES / 2017 (MILHARES R$)",
    "N2":" ",
    "N3":"A1 - ATIVIDADE CORE",
    "ANO_ANTERIOR":1214363,
    "ANO_ATUAL":1335800,
    "VAR":121437,
    "JAN":2388000,
    "FEV":2268000,
    "MAR":1728000,
    "ABR":2424000,
    "MAI":1464000,
    "JUN":2124000,
    "JUL":1212000,
    "AGO":1356000,
    "SET":2400000,
    "OUT":1800000,
    "NOV":0,
    "DEZ":0,
    "TOTAL":456291000
}]


function createTable(obj){
    // Criar a table
    $('#tbldados').append('<table></table>'); // Adiciona a tabela ao body
    var table = $('#tbldados').children('table'); // Seleciona a tabela

    // Criar o head da table
    var thead =  "<tr>";
    for (coluna in obj[0]) {
        thead += "<th>" + coluna + "</th>";
    }
    thead += "</tr>";
    $("<table>").show();

    //Criar o body da table
    var tbody = "<tr>";
    obj.forEach(function(linha,) {
        for (item in linha) {
            tbody += "<td>" + linha[item] + "</td>";
        }
        tbody += "</tr>";
    })



    // Adiciona a tabela completa ao body
}
$(document).ready(function(){
    createTable(dados);
});
```

Comment: Olá, não entendi muito bem o seu problema, tente explicar um pouco melhor

Comment: opa blz paulo eo seguinte eu tenho os "dados" e desejo criar uma tabela dinamica com esses dados porem nao esta exibindo a minha tabela no html gostaria de saber oque esta faltando botei $(document).ready e tudo porem nao esta exibindo a tabela

Comment: O cabeçalho aparece? O tbody você monta mas não chega a adocionar à tabela.

Comment: nao chega a aparecer nada ,eu dou append

Answer (score 1):

Seu código possui erros e ausência de código para formar a tabela. E deve usar `.append` após completar os laços. Após os laços, use o `.append` concatenando o resultados dos laços para inserir o resultado na `div`.

Um dos erros é:

```
$("<table>").show();
```

O seletor `<table>` é inválido. Deveria ser `$("table").show();`. Mas o `.show()` também não tem função alguma.

Veja o código corrigido:

```js
var dados =[{
    "N1":" CONTROLE DE GESTÃO ORCAMENTARIA CONCESSÕES - INDICADORES / 2017 (MILHARES R$)",
    "N2":" ",
    "N3":"A1 - ATIVIDADE CORE",
    "ANO_ANTERIOR":1214363,
    "ANO_ATUAL":1335800,
    "VAR":121437,
    "JAN":2388000,
    "FEV":2268000,
    "MAR":1728000,
    "ABR":2424000,
    "MAI":1464000,
    "JUN":2124000,
    "JUL":1212000,
    "AGO":1356000,
    "SET":2400000,
    "OUT":1800000,
    "NOV":0,
    "DEZ":0,
    "TOTAL":456291000
}];


function createTable(obj){
    // Criar a table
    $('#tbldados').append('<table></table>'); // Adiciona a tabela ao body
    var table = $('#tbldados').children('table'); // Seleciona a tabela

    // Criar o head da table
    var thead =  "<tr>";
    for (coluna in obj[0]) {
        thead += "<th>" + coluna + "</th>";
    }
    thead += "</tr>";

    //Criar o body da table
    var tbody = "<tr>";
    obj.forEach(function(linha,) {
        for (item in linha) {
            tbody += "<td>" + linha[item] + "</td>";
        }
        tbody += "</tr>";
    })

    // Adiciona a tabela completa ao body
    $("table").append(thead+tbody);
}
$(document).ready(function(){
    createTable(dados);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="tbldados"></div>
```

Comment: obrigado, eu so estava meio nervoso na sexta porem quando cheguei em casa e mexi acabei conseguindo